# Error inflating class fragment while implementing maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I am trying to add google map v2 and here is the main layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.test.map.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/atv_places"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:hint="@string/str_atv_places"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" 
    android:layout_below="@id/atv_places" />
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.map"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<permission
    android:name="com.test.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.test.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.map.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="mykey" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I have imported the play services library project and a copy of it in workspace

The above steps are taken from documentations provided by google. Now that, everything seems to be perfect and in place, I get the following exception:

```
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.map/com.test.map.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at com.test.map.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     ... 11 more
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at  com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at   com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.eb(Unknown Source)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at    com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at  android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153):     ... 21 more
```

Logcat is saying the following tag is missing, though I have it in my manifest.

```
02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:   A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Why I get this issue though everything is in place? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please use `FrameLayout` instead of `Fragment` in the layout file. Then create an instance of `supportmapfragment` in code and replace the `FrameLayout` with this fragment. It will solve your issue.

**XML:**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**In Code:**

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =  SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, supportMapFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to check your capitalization.

02-09 11:39:30.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5153): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment

Looks like you forgot to capatalize the Fragment class name.

```
<Fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" 
    android:layout_below="@id/atv_places" />
```

Comment: I did not get you, sorry. In the post, I have shown it as capitalized only - `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" ` . Or are you pointing to something else?

Comment: The stack trace you give points to the error, Error inflating class `fragment` on line #15 of the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

The meta-data tag must be a child of the application tag:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="mykey" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity ....
```